# JHipster-Registry Swagger UI for microservice says invalid_token with UAA

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I setup the following components using Jhipster (version of generator-jhipster: @ 5.3.1)

```
Gateway
Jhipster Registry
UAA Server
```

Everything works fine so far.

In Jhipster Registry, when I go to Administration >> API It opens up Swagger UI. Swagger UI lists the apis for Jhipster-Registry only. But it gives error when the uaa or gateway is selected in the drop down. Swagger UI From Gateway (Administration >> API) works fine. Only from registry it does not work.

Please let me know if I am missing some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UAA support for the registry was just recently added and will be in the next release.  If you want to have it early, you can make the following changes:

- In your UAA app's UaaConfiguration.java, add `.authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")` [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/8b933093a6aff87c90bef22e1c5894134c0ad231).
- Then you can use the `develop` tag for the `jhipster-registry` Docker image, and add the `uaa` profile to that container's `SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES`

  - If you prefer to run the JHipster Registry from source, you can clone the [`jhipster-registry` repository](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry) and check out the `develop` branch