# JHipster-Registry Metrics for microservice says Access is denied

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

setup the following components using Jhipster (version of generator-jhipster: @ 5.3.1)

Gateway
Jhipster Registry
UAA Server

Everything works fine so far.

In Jhipster Registry, when I go to Administration >> Application Metrics lists the apis for Jhipster-Registry only. But it gives error when the uaa or gateway is selected in the drop down.

```
[AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-09-14T09:17:14.584Z, principal=internal, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=remoteAddress=172.20.0.3, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

Please let me know if I am missing some configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JHipster-Registry Swagger UI for microservice says invalid\_token with UAA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311356/jhipster-registry-swagger-ui-for-microservice-says-invalid-token-with-uaa)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a UAA Server into a docker ?
The UAA Server docker is on the same network of the JHipster_Registry ?
You can try to use "--network host" to run the containers on the same network of the host.

F.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the `uaa` profile when you run the JHipster Registry